# Angular conditional validation on template driven form

Tags: angular, validation

I have an input field that is required only if another value is set.  The other value is from a select.  Note, my actual form is much more complicated but here is an example showing the parts that are pertinent to this question:

**the template:**

```
<form name="createPaymentForm" (ngSubmit)="f.form.valid && createPayment()" #f="ngForm" novalidate>

  <select name="orderNumberType" #orderNumberType="ngModel" 
    [(ngModel)]="payment.orderNumberType">
    <option [ngValue]="undefined" disabled>Select</option>
    <option *ngFor="let opt of paymentIdOptions" [value]="opt.id">{{opt.label}}</option>
  </select>

  <div [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': f.submitted && !orderNumber.valid }">
    <input type="text" name="orderNumber"
      [(ngModel)]="payment.orderNumber" #orderNumber="ngModel">
  </div>

</form>
```

**the component:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PaymentsService } from '../../../services/payments.service';
import { Payment } from '../../../models';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-new-payment',
  templateUrl: './new-payment.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./new-payment.component.scss']
})
export class NewPaymentComponent implements OnInit {
  paymentIdOptions: any = [];
  payment: Payment = {};

  constructor( private paymentsService: PaymentsService ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.paymentsService.getOrderNumberTypes().subscribe(orderNumberTypes => {
      this.paymentIdOptions = orderNumberTypes;
    });
  }

  createPayment() {
    console.log(this.payment);
    //do something...
  }
}
```

My goal is to only require the orderNumber if the orderNumberType is set to any value other than 'undefined'.  What is the easiest way to implement this?

(Note, Angular 5)

Comment: I would say that the *easiest* way is to use reactive forms instead since the ability to add/remove validation at runtime is one of its benefits. Baring that, however, you could add two input boxes each with an ngIf and only show the one with the required attribute if the other value is set.

Comment: Hmm,  that sounds like it might work (the two boxes with the ngif) but for some reason it feels wrong to me.  And sure i could use reactive forms, but I just spent the last few days trying to wrap my head around template driven forms.  I'm hoping that template driven forms can have all the same functionality as reactive ones otherwise why would the angular people even bother to offer you an incomplete solution?

Comment: Template driven is for simple and easy ... the kind of forms that just need straight-forward validation. Reactive forms is for anything that goes beyond the straight-forward. And no ... they are not feature compatible. Otherwise why would they offer two approaches. LOL. :-)

Comment: No i don't, not sure what pluralsight is but i have a very difficult time learning from videos (if that is what it is) and tutorials are almost always missing some critical information in my experience.  If i can't find an O'Reilly book on the subject then i'd just assume learn from trial and error.

Comment: @Dallas Caley Simply tried with  [required]="myCondition" ? Works from Angular 4.
this is similar than [attr.required]="myCondition ? true : undefined"
I use Reactive form in some projects and template driven in others and I can say that you can do exactly the same in the two ways.

Comment: @Gilsdav I sense that this is the solution but i'm not getting the syntax quite right.  I've added the following to my orderNumber input field: [required]="orderNumberType != 'undefined' ? true : undefined"

Comment: @Gilsdav...  This is even closer: [required]="payment.orderNumberType ? true : undefined"  In fact it actually works in the browser, the only problem now is i get this error in the console: Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'has-error: false'. Current value: 'has-error: true'.

Comment: @Dallas Caley [required] only need a boolean so give [required]="payment.orderNumberType" if your ids can not be (undefined, null, 0, false or empty string). If you only need to check if undefined [required]="payment.orderNumberType === undefined".

Comment: Allright, (only to see) can you replace [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': f.submitted && !orderNumber.valid }" by [class.has-error]="f.submitted && !orderNumber.valid" or something like that ? You can try to move "f.submitted && !orderNumber.valid" in a function too.

Comment: That fixed it  (specifically changing it to this: [class.has-error]="f.submitted && !orderNumber.valid")  post as the correct answer and i'll accept.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It can be done using **required Angular directive** like `[required]="payment.orderNumberType"` (here he check if payment.orderNumberType is undefined, null, 0, false or empty string).
This is a shorthand for `[attr.required]="payment.orderNumberType ? true : undefined"`.

You have problem with [ngClass]="{ 'has-error': f.submitted && !orderNumber.valid }" because valid will be set during "ngAfterViewChecked" so Angular don't want to make the job again.
Replacing it by `[class.has-error]="f.submitted && !orderNumber.valid"` will not make it cry anymore.

Comment: I have made the textbox required conditionally in the below way, hope it helps someone.
From the dropdown list based on the selected option.

onMLSChange(mlsId: string) {
        if (mlsId === 'MLS_Not_Listed') {
            this.hideAgentId = true;
        } else {
            this.hideAgentId = false;
        }
    }

In OnInit,
I made, this.hideAgentId = false;


I made the div as hidden using, [hidden]="!hideAgentId"
and made the field as required using [required]="hideAgentId"