# How to use ngForm for conditional validation of combined components

Tags: angular

I have a component where i have a user enter some information and I am using ngForm to do the field validation.

I have a angular material slide-toggle component which when active gets displays an input field for the user to enter some details.

The problem is that my submit button is not being enabled until the user fills a value for that field. I would like the ngForm validation to ignore that particular input field when the slide-toggle component is not in the active position.

Is there a simple way to do this?

My form looks like this:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="submitPost()" #episodeUploadform="ngForm">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="tags"
    #thetags="ngModel" name="tags" required>
  <mat-slide-toggle [color]="'active'" [checked]="allowBuy">Show Buy Button
  </mat-slide-toggle>
  <input type="url" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="buyUrl" [hidden]="!allowBuy" #buyurl="ngModel" name="buyurl" required>
</form>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular conditional validation on template driven form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48777059/angular-conditional-validation-on-template-driven-form)

Answer (score 0):

This was simply fixed by putting an *ngIf on the  instead of the [hidden] attribute.

I could not get the suggested duplicate fix to work...

Thanks.